# How do we specify path to the bootstrap 2.3 glyphicon icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

How do we specify the path to glyphicon icons [image](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons)

Currently, I have this setup

```
/assets
    --css
    ----lib (bootstrap css file here)
    --img (glyphicons here)
    --js (javascripts here)
```

I have this in my html view

```
<a class="btn btn-primary top-modal-slide" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal">
    <i class="icon-align-left"></i>
</a>
```

The image icon does not show up. If I trace the class that is applied to the above button for loading then it shows the following path.

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/assets/css/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
```

So, it is looked in `/assets/css/img` folder. How does bootstrap decide where to look for the glyphicons, and how can we change that. For example, in my case how do I configure it to look at

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
```

instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3:
Just check the bootstrap(.min).css, there is a @font-face definition for the glyphicons. Here you could change the paths.

Bootstrap 2:
Check the bootstrap(.min).css for the file path and change it to your relative filepath. Uncompressed version check line 2285 and 2309

Comment: I don't find the @font-face in the bootstrap 2 css files. I think what you are referring is related to bootstrap 3. I am using bootstrap 2.

Comment: But, I was still able to change the path by locating glyphicons-halflings image paths, in the bootstrap css min files. I have just changed them to my image paths, and they do work.

Comment: I changed my reply just before you commented, it now answers for version 2 & 3.